# Google geochart assign country colors based on criteria

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to assign country colors based on criteria?

I understand there's a color axis option which shades countries automatically based on a range of colors specified.

In my case I have representatives that belong to one or more countries, and want to explicitly assign one or more countries the same color.

How could I have control over this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Geochart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?csw=1#Example)
You can have countries to have same value to make them the same color

```
     var a;
     if (...) {
        a=1000; 
     }else {
        a=500;
     }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', a],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 800],
      ['RU', 1000]
    ]);

    var options = {
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']},
    };
```